# Fantasy movie with rings that shoot laser beams!

Tags: story-identification, movie

Every now and then this movie pops into my head that I watched as an early teenager. It was a fantasy movie where the main good and bad characters each have a ring of power that shoots a laser. I don't remember it being a sci-fi movie, more high fantasy style.

I think it would be from the early 80s to early 90s. A time when you could buy 5 weekly movies for $5 from your local video store.

Comment: Spaceballs? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pPkWZdluoUg

Comment: No, it wasn't sci-fi.

Comment: when i do a search, suggestions are 'Fire and Ice' 'Beast Master' 'Krull'

Comment: What about laser beams is not sci-fi? You may want to edit the question with more details.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back that you've found it. But please put that as an answer to your question.

Comment: @MrLister Star Wars has laser beams and it's not sci-fi. It's fantasy.

Comment: Laser beams! _pew pew pew_

Answer (score 19):

I came here to answer my own question. I think the movie I was after is *[Wizards of the Lost Kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizards_of_the_Lost_Kingdom)*.

> In the peaceful kingdom of Axeholme lives the teenage boy Simon, son of the king's court wizard. The evil wizard Shurka and his warriors (aided by the King's wife) kill the king and Simon's father and imprison the princess. Simon finds a sword while one of Shurka's men attack hearing his father's voice to use the sword killing him. Simon escapes, but loses the magic ring his father had given him.
>
> Meanwhile Shurka hypnotizes the princess to make her his disciple.
>
> Simon teams up with warrior Kor to free the kingdom and rescue the princess. Simon summons long-dead great warriors from their resting place using his powers to resurrect them, but only provokes the reanimated corpses into attacking him before they return to their graves. Traveling through the woods, Simon is tempted and seduced by the leader of a forest nymph coven, who is later revealed to be a spider creature working for Shurka. Kor and Simon stumble upon a hobgoblin's cottage which is attacked by lizard men. Simon uses magic to defeat them. The hobgoblin afterwards joins forces with Simon on his quest. Kor is then captured by cyclopses to be served at a wedding, though is rescued by Simon. The next day, while at a waterfall, they notice a woman drowning. Kor attempts a rescue, only to discover she is a fish-tailed Naiad and the guardian of the river. They have passed her test of heroism, allowing them to go further.
>
> Returning to the castle after exile, they release a group of townsfolk from prison, leading to a huge battle outside. Simon and Shurka face each other on the towers using white and black magic, with Shurka being blasted by his fireball. Simon and the princess are crowned the new King and Queen of Axeholme. Kor departs, looking for more adventure.

Comment: This movie was featured in the recent MST3k reboot:  http://mst3k.wikia.com/wiki/MST3K_1110_-_Wizards_of_the_Lost_Kingdom

Comment: When you answer your own question, you can accept the answer 48 hours after you asked the question, so in about two days, if we can have you come back to click on that checkmark... :)

Comment: I'm sure I'd have liked it if I was 12 in 1985...

Comment: Haha! So bad. I didn't know Gordon Ramsay was doing movies in 1985.

Comment: @mskfisher This is *the* movie that comes to my mind as the pinnacle of awful movies.  I will have to look up the MST3K showing.   Also, there is a sequel, though I've never seen it myself.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson the sequel is featured in the next episode.  :)

Comment: _pew pew-pew pew pewwwww_